# How do I integration test a node express controller?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

We started a node application where we are going to use Express as the router.  In one of our controllers, we have this defined:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// api/products
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json({ products: [] });
});

// api/products/:id
router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.json({ id: req.params.id });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I've been trying to follow examples on how to test this and came up with:

```
var hippie = require('hippie');
var server = require('../controllers/products');

describe('Products Controller Tests', function () {
    describe('/products endpoint', function () {
        it('returns an array of products', function (done) {
            hippie(server)
            .json()
            .get('/products')
            .expectStatus(200)
            .end(function (err, res, body) {
                if (err) throw err;
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But I'm always getting the following error:

Test Name:  Products Controller Tests /products endpoint returns an array of products
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result StandardOutput:
not ok 1 Products Controller Tests /products endpoint returns an array of products
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
      at Immediate. (C:\Api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:14)

## tests 1

## pass 0

## fail 1

What is the best way to unit test these controllers?  Is there a different library I should be using?

Comment: Are you trying to write integration tests or unit tests?

Comment: Sorry, integration test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about extracting the behaviour of your routes and unit testing that?

Something like this

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    routes = require('./routes');

router.get('/:id', routes.getId);
```

So that in your unit test you can have

```
describe('getId', function() {

  var route = require('../routes').getId;
  var req = // build your request object with params and so on
  var res = // stub this, for example with sinon

  it('whatever', function() {
    route(req, res);
    expect(res.send.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    // and so on
  });   

});
```

Once you're covered this with unit tests (faster to run, you can hook them up on pre-commit hook), you can integration test the route, without the need to mock the underlying HTTP library, with proper calls using `request` for example.